# When converges of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)$ implies converges of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f'(n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)$ exist at every $x\in[1,\infty)$. When the converges of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)
$$
implies the converges of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f'(n)\ ?
$$
Unfortunately, I didn't find any counterexample for this claim.

**My attempt**: I guess that there is a connection to the interchanging of the order of differentiation and summation.

Comment: Never. These sums can be totally independent. You can pick all of the values $f(1),f(2),f(3),\dots$ and $f'(1),f'(2),f'(3),\dots$ all independently of each other and there will be a function $f$ with those values.

Comment: Since $f'(n)$ only depends on the values close to $n,$ we can make $b_n=f'(n)$ be any sequence, no matter what $a_n=f(n)$ is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is at least one case: when $f'(x) \leq f(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$.

Comment: This might be true if you assume $f$ is a convex function.

Comment: Also, interchanging differentiation and summation is irrelevant since $\sum f(n)$ is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

The function $$f(x)=\dfrac{2+\sin(2\pi x^2)}{x^2}$$

is a counterexample to your statement.

Answer (score -1):

How about
$f(n)
=\dfrac{\sin(n^5)+2}{n^2}
$?

$\sum f(n)$
converges but
$\sum f'(n)$
diverges since
$f'(n)
=5 n^2 \cos(n^5) - \dfrac{2 \sin(n^5)+2}{n^3}
$.

Comment: The function has to be positive.

Comment: Easy fix - add 2 to numerator.

Comment: Ok, this works now (this is the exact same idea as my answer, except that proving the divergence of $\sum f'(n)$ requires some extra-work in your case...).

Answer (score -1):

A sufficient but not necessary condition is that there exists a natural $n$ such that $f'(i) \le f(i)$ for all $i \ge n$.

Every polynomial $f$ meets this condition. This can be proven as follows:

1. $f(x) > 0$ for every $x \in \left[ 0, \infty \right)$ implies that there exists a $a \ge 1$ such that f in increasing in the interval $\left[a, \infty \right)$, that is, $f'(x) \ge 0$ for every $x \in \left[ a, \infty \right)$.
2. $\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = 0$ implies that there exists $b \ge 1$ such that $\left| f'(x) \right| \le f(x)$ for all $x \ge b$.

1 and 2 together implies that there exists $n \ge \max(a, b)$ such that $f'(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x \ge n$.

Every function which meets the criteria above will have the property that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i)$ converges implies that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f'(i)$ converges.

Comment: The observation that polynomials satisfy your condition is somewhat vacuous since the sum $\sum f(n)$ will not converge for any polynomial but the zero polynomial.

Comment: @legionwhale that was an easy example I thought to demonstrate that if the rate of change of the derivative is smaller than the rate of change of the function then one convergence will imply the other.